# How to render a template without model.toJSON() in marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am converting my Backbone application to Marionette and couldn't find a solution to render my templates with a model but without toJSON(). As far as I know, Marionette automatically renders the template with this.model.toJSON()

Here is my backbone code:

`$(this.el).html(this.template(this.model))`

And in my templates I use stuff like:

```
<div>
  <% if (methodName()) { %>
    <%= get('attribute'); %>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [itemView documentation](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.itemview.html#itemview-serializedata) you just call render.

Marionette exposes a `rendered` event that you can listen to in order to append your view contents.

```
// ...snip

initialize: function () {
   this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
},

onRendererd: function (view) {
    // this is not exactly good practice
    // better handle this on the outside with a layout
    this.$el.appendTo($("#screens"));
}

// ...snip
```

To stay with Marionette convention however you should use [layouts and regions](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.region.html).

If you rely on the logic in your templates, a good idea would be to refactor your templates:

```
<div>
  <% if (booleanAttribute) { %>
    <%= attribute %>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

Then in your model use the `parse` method:

```
// ....snip
parse: function (response) {
    return _.defaults({
        booleanAttribute: this.method(response)
    }, response);
},
// ...snip
```

Comment: Marionette will call `model.toJSON() internally for you`. If you rely on passing the full Backbone model to the template (which you should never do), then I am afraid I have to say that you are doing it wrong. Sorry. If you really _must_ do this however, then you can overwrite [`view.seriealizeData`](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/item-view.js)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. If I may ask, why is it so wrong to pass the whole model?

Comment: I am in the camp of people advocating logic less templates. If you pass the whole Backbone model, you also have access you _all_ methods, which - most of the time - you don't need. It is all too tempting to call methods that transform the data from within your template. A template shouldn't have that power in my opinion.
The main reasons for me are:  
- performance (less method calls, less memory consumption)
- caching (parsing before rendering)
- debugging (smaller models)
- less exposure of your inner workings
These are just a few that come to my mind.

Comment: Cheers for the explanation Torsten! That makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this yet, but I suppose there's no reason why you can use Marionette's `templateHelper`. As per the docs:

> A `templateHelpers` attribute can be applied to any View object that
>   renders a template. When this attribute is present its contents
>   will be mixed in to the data object that comes back from the
>   `serializeData` method.

I'm thinking that instead of changing the way Marionette renders (not that there's anything wrong with that), simply make more data available to the template using `templateHelpers`. For your use-case, I would do something like:

```
templateHelpers: function () {
  return {
    get: function (attribute) {
      return this[attribute];
    }
  }
}
```

In this format, `this` inside `templateHelpers.get()` points to the serialized data, which is an object with property names that correspond to the view's model's attributes.